# On submit of a4j:commandlink i get random html of that action rather than html in JSF

Tags: jsf, seam

I am working with SEAM - JSF framework

I have following a4j commandlink on my xhtml page.

```
<a4j:commandLink id="rateImage" action="#{ratingSessionAction.rateImage}" oncomplete="getNewImageForSlider();"/>
```

When i click on this link first time after clearing my browser history, i get following html

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<link class="component"
    href="/abc/a4j/s/3_3_3.Finalorg/richfaces/renderkit/html/css/basic_classes.xcss/DATB/eAELXT5DOhSIAQ!sA18_"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link class="component"
    href="/abc/a4j/s/3_3_3.Finalorg/richfaces/renderkit/html/css/extended_classes.xcss/DATB/eAELXT5DOhSIAQ!sA18_"
    media="rich-extended-skinning" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script
    src="/abc/a4j/g/3_3_3.Finalorg.ajax4jsf.javascript.AjaxScript"
    type="text/javascript">

</script>
<script
    src="/abc/a4j/g/3_3_3.Finalorg/ajax4jsf/javascript/scripts/form.js"
    type="text/javascript">

</script>
<script
    src="/abc/a4j/g/3_3_3.Finalorg/richfaces/renderkit/html/scripts/skinning.js"
    type="text/javascript">

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <meta name="Ajax-Update-Ids" content="" />
    <span id="ajax-view-state"><input type="hidden"
        name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState"
        value="" />
    </span>
    <meta id="Ajax-Response" name="Ajax-Response" content="true" />
    <span id="org.ajax4jsf.oncomplete">getNewImageForSlider();</span>
</body>
</html>
```

> I removed value from viewstate hidden field purposely to reduce the
>   length of post.

Can anybody explain me why this is happening, and how can overcome it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you removed that value manually or it was the technology who did this for you?

Comment: I just removed the hidden field value manually, nothing else

Comment: Even i encountered this Issue

Answer (score 0):

Richfaces (a4j) is always returning you a complete html response. After the return it will use the ajax-update-id to split the response into parts and place them where you have the defined ids of your rerender attribute.

You are not specifing anything to rerender and because of that only your js should be executed oncomplete.

Either you can fetch a new image during the a4j request directly and use rerender (your page needs to be prepared for that with an img tag and a random src i suppose) or you gave to do this in your oncomplete callback and create a new img tag and place it yourself.

The second approach can be tricky because the server state will not be aligned in a next request assuming you are using conversations in seam for example